# is initializing an n-dimensional vector with constructor bad?

Tags: c++, stdvector

So, I recently figured out, that we can initialize an n sized vector with default values by writing e.g. `vector<int> x(n, default_value)`.

This can also be applied to n dimensional vectors, e.g. n=3:

```cpp
vector<vector<vector<int>>> x(n, vector(n, vector(n, default_value)))
```

Has this approach any advantages or disadvantages over doing:

```cpp
vector<vector<vector<int>>> x;
x.resize(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    x[i].resize(n);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        x[i][j].resize(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: One version is 1 line long, and the other uses 10 lines of code. I see no advantage of using more code.

Comment: They're not equivalent, so start with that. The latter doesn't promote `default_value` into the inner-most cells. Also, The former is basically making copies of the 'value' field at each dimension. The latter doesn't do that either. Decide for yourself whether that differential behavior is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one first creates `default_value` for each vector and then copies it to the destinations, so you get `(n+1)^k` allocations instead of `n^k`.

You forgot to initialize the integer-based vector. Therefore I argue the first version is less error-prone ;) It's also much cleaner and shows the intention clearly.

Although second could benefit from `for(auto& c:vec)` loops instead of indices. Or `std::for_each`, or any other loop-hiding stuff... Anyway you are doing initialization -> just use constructors.